# Iterating cursor on big collection in mongo and node doesn't return all results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection that has 500k documents (collection takes about 
130mb)

I'm using the standard mongodb driver:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
```

I'm trying to iterate through this collection in node.js, using a cursor. (because .toArray takes too long to put entire dataset in memory)

```
var cursor = db.collection('test').find({});

cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
   // only does this 1000 times
});
```

I found that it only did it 1000 times, so I looked at the documentation https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html and under the "each" section, it said to increase the batch size.

So I made an extremely large batch size, I didn't find a way to make it unlimited. If you know a way let me know.

```
var cursor = db.collection('test').find({}).batchSize(1000000000000);
cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    // only does this 30382 times
});
```

And increasing the batch size any more doesn't make it iterate on more elements then 30382.

How can I make `cursor.each()` iterate 500,000 times?

Answer (score 2):

You can track the index and on error you can continue from where you left again:

```
const iterateCollection = (skip) => {
 const cursor = db.collection('test').find({}).skip(skip);
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
   skip++;
   if(err){
     //if err due to overflow
     iterateCollection (skip)
   }
 });
};

iterateCollection(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this with using "forEach" instead of "each"... I have no idea what the difference is, all I know it works so far. so

```
var cursor = db.collection('test').find();

cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
   // do stuff, does it 500,000 times for my collection...

}, function(err) {
    // finished
  db.close();
});
```

Only problem now is forEach is slow as molasses in january, so would be interested in hearing other solutions.